# How to pass "type" as input parameter to func in Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, types, database-migration, postgresql-9.5

Looking forward for PostgreSQL equivalent code. Please help. Problem while doing database migration from SQL Server to Postgresql.

SQL Server code:

```
 CREATE TYPE [InactiveOwnDetails] AS TABLE
                                        (
                                            [EntType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
                                            [EntName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
                                        )
    
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GenerateInactiveOwnEmail]
    AS
        DECLARE @InactiveOwnDetails InactiveOwnDetails
            
      
        INSERT INTO InactiveOwnEmailActivity (Subject_Email)
        VALUES (
SELECT **Fn_GetInactivePpMailBodyContent**(@InactiveOwnDetails)
)

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[**Fn_GetInactivePpMailBodyContent**]
        (@InactiveOwnDetails InactiveOwnDetails READONLY)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultString = '<p> Dear'+CAST(12 AS NVARCHAR)+', '
        RETURN @ResultString
    END
```

Please help!

Comment: It's unclear to me what that function does. It seems you pass a single "type" (or record), rather than a "table" to the function. I also don't understand how `@InactiveOwnDetails` gets populated to begin with.

Comment: Yes its a type...how to pass a type in postgresql...can you help me translating the above code ...

Comment: So how does `@InactiveOwnDetails` gets populated with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the direct question, you can pass a (record) type to a function:

```
CREATE TYPE inactive_own_details as (ent_type varchar(10), ent_name varchar(400));
```

You can create a function that receives that type and returns something:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetInactivePpMailBodyContent(p_details inactive_own_details)
  RETURNS text
AS
$$
  select concat('<p> Dear', p_details.ent_name, '</p>');
$$
language sql;
```

The function in the question doesn't make sense to me as it doesn't use the passed type at all.

In the procedure you can use it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_generateinactiveownemail()
AS
$$
declare
  l_details inactive_own_details;
begin
  l_details := ('type', 'Arthur'); -- initialize the variable

  INSERT INTO inactiveownemailactivity (subject_email)
  VALUES (SELECT fn_getinactiveppmailbodycontent(l_details));
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Note: `create procedure` requires Postgres 11 or later. You have tagged your question with Postres 9.5 - which is about to be deprecated in about 6 months. A new migration project should definitely **not** use that version in 2020. You should migrate to Postgres 12 instead.